# cocos2d-x pure virtual method error only in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, cocos2d-x

I'm following a Korean cocos2d-x book and example code is compiled and runs well in xcode & ios.

But eclipse complains about pure virtual method(The code is exactly same!)

Below is the error message.

The type 'GameObject' must implement the inherited pure virtual method 'cocos2d::CCRGBAProtocol::setOpacity'

`class GameObject : public CCSprite`

The code is nothing special. Defines a GameObject class and inherits from CCSprite.

I think CCRGBAProtocol or setOpacity is not necessary. Why is eclipse complains about that?

Thanks in advance.

(cocos2d-x version is 2.2, android project file is generated by cocos2d-x default script)

Comment: Have you added your class to Android.mk?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have same issue before, it turns out should be Eclipse Code Analysis plug-in issue. Do the followings should resolve your issue.

On your eclipse project, `right click -> properties`

Under `C/C++ General -> Code Analysis`

choose "`Use project setting`"

then un-check the following checking:

Syntax and `Semantic Errors-> Abstract class cannot be instantiated`

It should resolve your issue.

Comment: By unticking the "Semantic Errors-> Abstract class cannot be instantiated" is not a solution.We need to fix the problem..

Answer (score -1):

You may have mis-spelled the 'setOpacity' function down on GameObject class! Otherwise clean-and-build step may help you.

Comment: I did not override setOpacity. Like I said I don't think setOpacity is necessary. And I tried clean-and-rebuild and it didn't work. Thank you .

Comment: Have you tried building android project from command-line? My thought is if c++ code builds fine in Xcode, then it should surely work in eclipse as well!